# How to pass Numpy PyArray* via FFI

Tags: python, numpy, python-cffi

Idea is to be able to modify array from library, like an "output" from a function.
Example:

```
ffi.cdef("""
    //Reads data from a file, and store in the numpy array
    void read_image(PyArray* arr);
""")

C = ffi.dlopen('libimage.so')
image = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
C.read_image(image)
assert image.ndim == 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass CPython-specific `PyXxx` structures via CFFI: you need to pass standard C data.  Normally I'd answer that you need to design your cdef()'ed function with a standard C interface, for example something like:

```
ffi.cdef("""
    struct myimage_t {
        int width, height;
        float *data;
    };
    int read_image(struct myimage_t *output);  // fill in '*output'
    void free_image(struct myimage_t *img);   // free output->data
""")

myimage = ffi.new("struct myimage_t *")
if lib.read_image(myimage) < 0:
    raise IOError
...
lib.free_image(myimage)
```

Then you need to manually convert the `myimage` to a numpy array, somewhere in the "..." code above.

One better alternative is to use a Python callback: a callback that makes the numpy array according to spec and returns a C-standard `float *` pointer.  The numpy array itself is saved somewhere in the callback.  You could save it as a Python global, or more cleanly use a "handle" you pass via C.  Requires the API version, not the ABI.  In _example_build.py:

```
ffi.cdef("""
   extern "Python" float *alloc_2d_numpy_array(void *handle, int w, int h);
   void read_image(void *handle);
""")
ffi.set_source("_example_cffi", """
   void read_image(void *handle)
   {
       // the C code that eventually invokes
       float *p = alloc_2d_numpy_array(handle, w, h);
        // and then fill the data at 'p'
   }
""")
ffi.compile(verbose=True)
```

In file example.py:

```
from _example_cffi import ffi, lib

class Context:
    pass

@ffi.def_extern()
def alloc_2d_numpy_array(handle, w, h):
    context = ffi.from_handle(handle)
    context.image = np.ndarray([w, h], dtype=np.float32)
    return ffi.cast("float *", ffi.from_buffer(context.image))

context = Context()
lib.read_image(ffi.new_handle(context))
image = context.image
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your reply. It's sad we can't do this... we lose access to numpy's array C API. In torch we have easy direct access to their matrix objects using FFI and it helps a lot.

Comment: It's like being sad that your x86 executables don't work any more on an ARM smartphone.  If you have code that manipulates PyObjects using the CPython C API, then yes, it can't work with cffi; that's part of the design goals of cffi.  My answer gives examples of how to achieve the same results using cffi's approach---with a callback written in Python whenever you need to access some Python object.